# How to synchronize insert/removal of elements to/from a data structure, the Functional Way?

Tags: multithreading, scala, functional-programming, thread-safety

I have a data structure, say a `MinHeap`. It has methods like peek(), removeElement() and addElement(). `removeElement()` and `addElement()` can produce inconsistent states if they are not made thread safe (because they involve increasing/decreasing the currentHeapSize).
Now, I want to implement this data structure, the functional way. I have read that in functional programming immutability is the key which leads to thread safety. How do I implement that here? Should I avoid incrementing/decrementing the currentHeapSize? If so, how? I would like some direction with this.

**Edit #1**
@YuvalItzchakov and @Dima have pointed out saying that I need to return a new collection everytime I do an insert/delete, which makes sense. But wouldn't that hamper the performance critically?
My use case is that I will be getting a stream of data and I keep adding it to the heap. When ever someone requests data, the root of the min heap is returned. So here insertion happens very rapidly. Wouldn't creating a new Heap for every insert prove to be costly? I think it would. If so, how does functional programming really help? Is it just a theoretical concept or does it have practical implications as well?

Comment: Immutability means that the object can never be changed, once created. If you want your heap to be immutable, that means that `add` and `remove` should return a new instance of the heap.

Comment: If you look at existing immutable collections in Scala, such as `List`, `Map` and the likes, you can see that each mutation returns a *new* collection. You should do the same with your `MinHeap`, it needs to produce the new instance with that element removed, added, etc.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov : Got it. But wouldn't that hamper performance very much. By performance I mean I have to copy the exiting heap and return a new one. I will edit my question with a use case.

Comment: @Dima : Thanks for the comment. Can you please check out my edit?

Comment: That really depends on your performance requirements. Let's start over, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov : There is a stream of incoming data (say integers). I am adding that data to a MinHeap as it comes. But there is also an API exposed that will get the MinValue from this heap (i.e the root of this heap.will be removed and sent as the result. The heap will have to be again brought back to a stable state). So there is one thread continuously inserting data into the Heap and another removing the root  of the Heap on request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of parallel access to the same data structure is twofold. First, we need to serialize parallel updates. @Tim gave a comprehensive answer to this. Second, in the case there are many readers, we may want to allow them to read in parallel with writing. And in this case immutability plays its role. Without it, writers have to wait the readers to finish.

Comment: Interesting. In case of reading why is it required to return an immutable structure? I can return a copy of the exiting heap. But does it necessarily have to be immutable?

Comment: It may be mutable but since a reader is not supposed to mutate it, it does not matter. Just to double check, to fail fast if a faulty reader would try to mutate it.

Comment: @Ashwin As I said in my answer, it is not a good idea to return the whole heap to lots of different threads. Instead, define specific queries on the heap and return the result of those queries. So you mention getting the `MinValue` from the heap and this request should just return that minimum value. You could even allow clients to run their own queries on the heap, passed in as a function.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "functional" way to have a data structure that can be updated by multiple threads.  In fact one reason that functional programming is so good in a multi-threaded environment is because there aren't any shared data structures like this.

However in the real world this problem comes up all the time, so you need some way to serialise access to the shared data structure. The most crude way is simply to put a big lock around the whole code and only allow one thread to run at once (e.g. with a Mutex). With clever design this can be made reasonably efficient, but it can be difficult to get right and complicated to maintain.

A more sophisticated approach is to have a thread-safe queue of requests to your data structure and a single worker thread that processes these requests one-by-one.  One popular framework that supports this model is Akka Actors. You wrap your data structure in an `Actor` which then receives requests to read or modify the data structure. The Akka framework will ensure that only one message is processed at once.

In your case your the actor would manage the heap and receive updates from the stream which would go into the heap. Other threads can then make requests that will be processes in a sequential, thread-safe way. It is best if these request perform specific queries on the heap, rather than just returning the whole heap every time.

Answer (score 0):

You may use cats Ref type class 
https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/concurrency/ref.html
But it is that AtomicReference realization, or write some  java.util.concurent.ConcurentHashMap wrapper